# Macro treat keys as true when defined

Tags: macros, common-lisp, elisp

Is is possible to treat a key as true when using `cl-defmacro`s in elisp? For example,

```
(cl-defmacro mac (&key a b c)
  `(,@(if a "a" (if b "b" "c"))))

(mac :a)
"c"
```

Can I have that evaluate to "a" without needing to give `:a` a value like `(mac :a t`). I don't know if the same semantics apply to common-lisp

Comment: Keywords in Common Lisp are always paired as key and value. What would the purpose to omit a value - compared to omit the key AND the value.

Comment: the purpose would be simplication. To me, it is much nicer to write `(mac :a)` than to need to write `(mac :a 1)` when the value doesn't even matter

Comment: why not write `(mac)` when the value does not matter. How should Lisp tell what `(mac :a :b :c)` means? Are those keys? values? key :a with value :b and key :c? key :a, key :b and key :c?

Comment: when I said value there I was referring to the object following the key `:a`. The keys matter here, eg `:a` since they determine the return value. I don't know how lisp parses its arguments, that's why I was asking. I would assume that it does know the names of function parameters in its symbol table though

Comment: I'm sure there are idiomatic ways of doing what I'm trying to do -- which is just have a bunch of named switches as arguments, but without the enforced argument ordering

Comment: In Common Lisp keys are also values. (foo :a :b) might mean key :a and value :b.

Comment: ok, thanks, that makes sense to me, so I guess there is nothing like `&swtich` that could specify switches instead. I suppose you would need to use something like a `cond` in the body then  instead?

Comment: You could change the meaning of keywords in lambda lists for your own macros. That requires you to emit code that parses arguments according to your own logic: `(mydef foo (a b c) ...` would become for example: `(defun foo (&rest args) (let (a b c) (dolist (arg args) (case arg (:a (setf a t)) (:b (setf b t)) (:c (setf c t)))) ... ))`

Comment: Usually in Lisp you would not use the keyword/value mechanism. But you can use a list of all the arguments and check them manually. If you need that often and COND seems to be difficult to write, you might be able to write another macro for that, which you can use inside your macro...

Comment: thanks guys, I had thought about similar approaches, but they just seemed like a lot more work than what I was trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do this with the base language. One could define a `defun` like macro to do this. Would you want to *only* allow these to be set to true or would you want to give values other than `t` (or `nil` be omission)? The first case can be done by writing some macros. The second case can’t be done in a nice way (specifically would `(mac :a :b)` do `a <- t; b <- t` or `a <- :b`?)

Here is something you could write for Common Lisp:

```
(defmacro keyset-bind (keys-and-vars form &body body)
  (let (syms vars
        (keyv (gensym "KEY")))
    (loop for key in keys-and-vars
      for sym = (if (consp key)
                    (car key)
                    (intern (symbol-name key) "KEYWORD"))
      for var = (if (consp key) (cadr key) key)
      collect sym into symst
      collect var into varst
      finally (setf syms symst vars varst))
    `(let ,vars
        (loop for ,keyv in ,form
          do (case ,keyv
               ,@(loop for sym in syms
                   for var in vars
                   collect `((,sym) (setf ,var t)))
               (t (error "unrecognised keyword ~a" ,keyv))))
        ,@body)))
```

And then you can use it like:

```
(defun mac (&rest switches)
  (keyset-bind (a b (:t foo)) switches
    (list a b foo)))

CL-USER> (mac :a)
(T NIL NIL)
CL-USER> (mac :b :t)
(NIL NIL T)
CL-USER> (mac :baz)
;; Error ...
```

One could write an alternative `defun` which accepted eg a `&switch` argument type in this way but then you would need to decide how to make it interact with other argument types and keywords and `&allow-other-keys` and `:allow-other-keys t`. In general all of this is a bad idea and any kind of mixing with (or even usage of) the above is discouraged as it makes it hard to know whether an unfamiliar function call will be interpreted as normal keywords or set-of-keywords. If you want a language which supports this kind of thing, look at perl6 where keywords are a key-value-pair type and there is special syntax for `key => true` and `key => false`.